# Сохранить информацию, полученную из анализа N изображений, в другую директорию в отдельный файл для каждой каринки

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-символов

Здравствуйте.
Пишу код, анализирующий изображения. Необходимо извлечь информацию, распознанную на скрине, и сохранить в файл. Для 1 изображения всё работает:

```
def ocr_space_file(filename, overlay=True, api_key='myAPI', language='eng'):

    payload = {'isOverlayRequired': overlay,
               'apikey': api_key,
               'language': language,
               }
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        r = requests.post('https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
                          files={filename: f},
                          data=payload,
                          )

    Info = r.content.decode()
    obj = json.loads(Info)

    f = open('Data.txt', 'w')
    for i in obj['ParsedResults']:
        for j in range(0,len(i["TextOverlay"]['Lines'])):
            allInfo = i["TextOverlay"]['Lines'][j]['Words']
            for k in allInfo:
                text = k['WordText']
                coords = [k['Left'],k['Top'],k['Width'],k['Height']]
                f1 = ','.join(map(str, coords))
                f.write(text+ " "+ f1 + '\n' )
    f.close()
    return r.content.decode()

    test_file = ocr_space_file(filename='1my.png', language='eng')
```

Но затем, когда я пытаюсь так же обработать все изображения в директории, всё почему-то пишется в один файл Data.txt, вместо того, чтобы создавать каждый раз новый. 
Закомменчены также остатки от попыток сохранить так, как работало с Images, но для str стало нерелевантно. Пытался ещё так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024248/telling-python-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-certain-directory-on-windows-and-mac, тоже не пашет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что именно я делаю не так. Явно в функции вместо создания идёт перезапись, но я не знаю, как фиксить.

```
imagePaths = [f for f in glob.glob('cropped_images/*.png')]
save_path = 'Labeled_images/'

def ocr_all_screenshots():

    for pic in imagePaths:

        #src_fname, ext = os.path.splitext(pic)  # split filename and extension   
        # construct output filename, basename to remove input directory
        #save_fname = os.path.join(save_path, os.path.basename(src_fname) + '_labeled.png')
        os.chdir(save_path)
        ocr_space_file(pic)

ocr_all_screenshots()
```

Comment: Замените: `open('Data.txt', 'w')` --> `open(filename, 'w')`

Comment: Cпасибо, но так тоже не работает: пишет TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

надо для каждого нового файла открывать на запись новый файл с другим именем.
что то вроде такого.

```
def ocr_space_file(filename, overlay=True, api_key='мой API', language='eng'):
    ...обработка json
    for count, i in enumerate(obj['ParsedResults']):
        f = open('Data' +str(count) +'.txt', 'w')
        ...
        f1 = ','.join(map(str, coords))
        f.write(f1 + '\n' )
        f.close()
        return r.content.decode()
```

что по сути работает примерно так:

```
 def ocr_space_file(filename, overlay=True, api_key='мой API', language='eng'):
    ...обработка json
    count = 0
    for i in obj['ParsedResults']:
        count +=1
        f = open('Data' + str(count) +'.txt', 'w')
        ...
        f1 = ','.join(map(str, coords))
        f.write(f1 + '\n' )
        f.close()
        return r.content.decode()
```

Comment: OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long:
Он в имя пытается всю информацию в Data поставить

Comment: спасибо за совет, попробовал. Не решает проблемы, т.к. первая строка  `for i in obj['ParsedResults'] ` итерирует внутри одного jsona (там структура ParsedResults{TextOverlay{Lines{...}}}), а не по нескольким.